# Automatic Line Break in HTML

Tags: html, css

[pic 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JTUuJ.jpg)

Okay, so I am being force to line break, however there is plenty of room in the line to fit all of the characters. I want it to be "2 Go" on the third line, but in my HTML if I put a space in between it forces the line break.

Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<div class="col-sm-3">
  <p class="lead wall-sticker">
    Shoe
    <br> Shine
    <br> 2 Go
    <br>
    <a href="#features">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Learn More</button>
    </a>
  </p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wall-sticker {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  padding: 1rem 20rem 1rem 3rem;
  font-family: "FiveBoroughsHandwriting";
  font-size: 7rem;
  color: white;
}
```

I think is problem with HTML not CSS. Please see: https://jsfiddle.net/dwzc0fr7/

Comment: You need to include your HTML code and related CSS if you want us to be able to help you.

Comment: Please show me jsfiddle.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/dzcw74f0/1/ seems to be working fine, you mean when decreasing viewport width for mobile the word "Go" will be pushed down?

Answer (score 0):

Let's try another work-around

- Remove the padding: `padding: 1rem 3rem 1rem 3rem;` from `.wall-sticker`.
- Add `text-align: center;` to `.wall-sticker`.
- Change `.col-sm-3` to `.col-sm-4` & add `.col-md-4` as well.
- Change `.col-sm-9` to `.col-sm-8` & add `.col-md-8` as well.
- Remove white space after words - e.g. `Shoe<br>`, `Shine<br>` & `2 Go<br>`.

[Check Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dwzc0fr7/4/)

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm sorry but i don't follow, you added more html for what purpose? What you wanted was not to break "2 Go" line, don't know why you've added more html and removed css frankly.

Comment: Sorry, that was my mistake! But on my index.html it still does not change the link break even if I make the browser larger or make the font size smaller!

Comment: My friend there goes a last attempt, hope it helps otherwise I apologize for being unable to help. Regards.